# Hepatic lobules and hepatocytes

Tags: digestive-system, liver

> "The hepatic lobules are the structural and functional units of the liver containing hepatic cells arranged in the form of cords. "

My textbook says that the hepatic lobule is the structural and functional unit of the liver. I'm confused as to why don't call hepatocytes the structural and functional unit of the liver instead, as they are the actual units secreting phospholipids, bilirubin and other components of the bile juice.

I framed this answer based on my understanding, please verify if I'm right or not and do suggest improvements-
"Properties of the hepatic lobule are not present in hepatocytes, they arise due to the interaction of hepatocytes. Therefore, hepatocytes on their own, cannot be termed as a functional and structural unit of the liver"

Comment: Who is "it"? What are the **functions** of the liver? There is more than one.

Comment: "It" refers to my books and teachers. They say that a single hepatic lobule is capable of performing all the designated functions of a liver. But that doesn't make sense to me, aren't hepatocytes capable of doing all of them in the first place??

Comment: My question about "It" was meant to prod you into citing your source. A bit of research on your part is expected. No, a hepatocyte can't perform all the functions of the liver. Why would I ask that question if you were correct?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Related question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89056/functional-unit

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information. ——— Also note that [quotes and excerpts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) **must** be referenced. This is generally considered good practice in scientific communication, avoids plagiarism, and will help other users by providing context.